# QTableView set the color of a specific row

Tags: c++, qt

I know there are plenty of discussion on forums and here about this subject but I could not find a working solution for this problem.

I have a QTableView that uses a model. I need to be able to change the background color of some specific rows through the model, more precisely from the `data` function.

```
QVariant CCustomModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
  if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
  {

    switch (index.column())
    {
      case colName:         return QVariant(QString::number(1));
      case colAdress:       return QVariant(QString::number(2));
      case colGender:       return QVariant(QString::number(3));
      case colTelephone:    return QVariant(QString::number(4));
      default:
        return QVariant();
    }
  }

  if(role == Qt::BackgroundColorRole)  //also tried Qt::BackgroundRole and Qt::ForegroundRole
  {
    return QVariant(QColor(Qt::red));
  }
  return QVariant();
}
```

This is simple not working. The numbers are displayed but the background color is still the basic one. Is there any possible solution here?

Comment: Did you somehow restrict the roles which will be requested from the model? Does the code actually get to the statement and it just will not draw red? Or do you never get a request for the role `BackgroundColorRole`?

Comment: I tested and I always get a request for that role. I have restriction just on flags to not be selectable or editable but I do not thing this is the problem.

Comment: Also if I use return QVariant(QColor(Qt::red)); outside the role check I receive in each cell a small red squareand the number next to it but that is it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  if(role == Qt::BackgroundRole) 
  {
      return QBrush(QColor(Qt::red));
  }
```